# is it possible to create a view from another view?

Tags: mysql, view, mysql-workbench

It's probably a silly question but it is straight forward.

Is it possible to create a view from an existing view?

Let's say I've tableA. I create vwtableA from tableA and now I want to create vvVwtableA from vwtableA.

In pseudo-code it would be something like:

```
create view vwA as select * from tableA;
create view vwvwA as select * from vwA;
```

is this possible?
I'm trying something like this and I get no MySQL errors executing the statment but I can't browse the second view... MySQL Workbench keeps loading for ever and I don't know if this may be the cause.

My tableA has around 100 000 records, vwA has around 50 000 records and vwvwA should have around 50 000 as well.

Comment: What does `SHOW PROCESSLIST` show? Maybe there's some brute of a query running when your workbench app is waiting.

Comment: I get this `'1', 'root', 'localhost:50323', 'tese', 'Query', '0', NULL, 'SHOW PROCESSLIST'
'2', 'root', 'localhost:50326', 'tese', 'Sleep', '1', '', NULL
` which looks normal I guess...

Comment: which software you used for mysql?

Comment: Have you tried another front-end tool to see if it's Workbench that's having the problem?

Comment: Now I got this, when I stopped the `select * from vwVwtablea limit 0,10`

`'1', 'root', 'localhost:50323', 'test', 'Query', '0', NULL, 'SHOW PROCESSLIST'
'2', 'root', 'localhost:50326', 'test', 'Sleep', '23', '', NULL
'3', 'root', 'localhost:51142', 'test', 'Query', '29', 'Copying to tmp table', 'SELECT 1 FROM `test`.`vwnumrows2` LIMIT 100000'
`

vwnumrows2 is in this case vwVwtablea

Comment: @chintan I'm using mysql workbench and sometimes phpmyAdmin and both freeze with that simple select and generate no output at all.

Comment: @tadman yes I tried with phpMyAdmin and it's the same.

Comment: may be something wrong in this view.Try select * from tableA limit 0,10; and say it's work or not?

Comment: @chintan yes that one works as expected.

Comment: It means,Problem is in the View(vwA). You have to make this view again.It will work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. See MySQL [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-view.html)

> The select_statement is a SELECT statement that provides the definition of the view. (When you select from the view, you select in effect using the SELECT statement.) select_statement can select from base tables **or other views**

Comment: Thanks, then it has to be something wrong with workbench or the views itself to not be able to do a simple `select * from vwVwtablea limit 0,10` as it keeps running/loading/processing and does not generates anything

Comment: Potentially. Try terminal/command line first to make sure before you blame Workbench.

Answer (score 0):

just make a copy of your first view (vwA) and create a new one (vwvwA) . Simple this way.  ;-)

Comment: I can't copy because they wont have the exact same data stored